# What are the permissions required for CIMSessions

Tags: powershell

I need to query some WMI classes on Servers that I do not have permissions.
Here is the error I get when I run it.

```
PS> get-ciminstance -ComputerName test.mydomain.com -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem
get-ciminstance : Access is denied.
At line:1 char:1
+ get-ciminstance -ComputerName test.mydomain.com -ClassName Win32_Operating ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (root\cimv2:Win32_OperatingSystem:String) [Get-CimInstance], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070005,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.GetCimInstanceCommand
    + PSComputerName        : test.mydomain.com
```

Right now server has PowerShell 2, so it uses DCOM but I will get the PowerShell upgraded and configured to allow WSMAN connections.

But what are the permissions that need to be granted to the account?

Comment: Do you have admin rights to that server?

Comment: I do not have any rights on the server at the moment. So, I am trying to understand what's the 'minimum' I need to ask them to grant me.

Answer (score 7):

By default, `Administrators` (local) and `Authenticated Users` (domain) have at least read rights to the namespace.  You need to ensure you can login/authenticate to the server.  It's worth mentioning that the `Authenticated Users` group does not have `Remote Enable` permission by default.

The Windows OS uses WinRM for CIM cmdlets and the user account needs to be an `administrator`.  WinRM makes a local group called `WinRMRemoteWMIUsers_` and gives access to just the `Administrators` group and `WinRMRemoteWMIUsers_`.  To add a user to that group use the following command:

```
net localgroup WinRMRemoteWMIUsers__ /add "domain\user"
```

The abstract answer is simply that you need to be granted `Enable Account` and `Remote Enable` permissions to the `Namespace` to have WMI *read* rights remotely.

**Process to Verify WMI Permissions**

Login to the server and launch mmc.exe.  Add the WMI snapin and once it loads, right click on WMI Control. When the Properties window opens, click security,  expand root and select cimv2.  Click the security button and view who is granted access and what access is granted.

**Script to Test w/ DCOM**

If you want to test using DCOM, or need to because the server OS is too old,  use this script:

```
$Computer = thisbox.domain.com
$CimOption = New-CimSessionOption -Protocol Dcom
$CimSession = New-CimSession -ComputerName $Computer -SessionOption $CimOption

Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_operatingsystem -CimSession $CimSession
```

Comment: DCOM is an entirely different animal with it's own security settings and is managed with `dcomcnfg.exe`.  By default `Self` has `Access Permissions` for local and remote.  Check out this answer to the inevitable question of "what is self" :)  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/ed147d85-d288-402b-ad14-bf7b6c466022/detailed-explanation-of-the-self-user-group-and-whenwhy-it-is-used?forum=winserverDS

Comment: Are you in a domain environment?  If in a domain, are you using a domain account or local account for authentication?  What's the OS for the server?  DCOM would be needed for older windows OS's...  Is the connection refusal error the same?

Comment: Also, Windows uses WinRM for CIM cmdlets, what was the command used to configure WinRM on the server (if it's a windows box)?

Comment: Wait...  The user account isn't an admin?  I must have missed that.  Yes, admin is required.  I'm going to update my answer with that expressly stated, and a script you can use to test using DCOM.

Comment: I thought I would just blog about it rather than trying to explain: http://www.adilhindistan.com/2013/10/permissions-to-access-wmi-remotely.html I would like to mark your answer as solution, if you would like to incorporate the steps I mentioned there. Mainly: Add user to DCOM group and make sure to choose all namespaces under root when applying (default is this name space only, which does not work)

Comment: Note that when accessing the local machine, `Get-CimInstance` might not work with `-ComputerName localhost` (access denied), but can work without it.  This was seen with a virtual service account on Windows 10 21H2.