# How to run `Get-CimInstance` as non-admin user (windows server 2019, powershell 5.1)

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2019, powershell-5.1

I am trying to run a powershell command on a server very similar to this one.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55942155/4577279

The problem is that the script is being run by a non-admin user, and it fails to run the
`Get-CimInstance` command.

it fails with

```
Get-CimInstance : Access denied 
At C:\bin\SCRIPT.ps1:6 char:5
+     Get-CimInstance Win32_Process | ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (root\cimv2:Win32_Process:String) [Get-CimInstance], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80041003,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.GetCimInstanceCommand
```

The command is run by an instance of windows server 2019 on a remote box. The script in question is on the box as well.

How can I allow for the non-admin user to run this command without having to run it as administrator? I am in full control of the server and can modify the permissions, but I'm not sure how to approach that. The script **should** be run by a non-admin if at all possible.

alternatively if there is a different way to get the entire children process tree for a given PID, that could work, too.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

By default, `Administrators` (local) and `Authenticated Users` (domain) have at least read rights to the namespace. You need to ensure you can login/authenticate to the server. It's worth mentioning that the `Authenticated Users` group does not have `Remote Enable` permission by default. see this answer for more information - [What are the permissions required for CIMSessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19279099/what-are-the-permissions-required-for-cimsessions)