# Disabling a display adapter device via powershell is returning error

Tags: powershell

**Objective**

Disable and re-enable a display adapter via Powershell to make it work again after Windows puts it to sleep.

**Scenario description**

My GPU card sits on an eGPU enclosure connected via Thunderbolt to my laptop.
When the laptop awakes from sleep, all the peripherals connected to the eGPU work well (mouse, keyboard, webcam, etc) but the GPU card doesn't.

I'm assuming this has to do with the power saving settings when Windows goes to sleep and the way the eGPU handles the GPU card but until recently I found no other solution rather than rebooting the machine.

Last week I found a work around. I can manually disable and then re-enable the display adapter in the device manager. I do this about 5-6 times a day and it's much better than rebooting the whole machine and waiting for it to reopen all my apps and browser tabs for my dev work.

So then I thought, instead of manually opening the device manager, what if I created a powershell script for this? This obviously is not life and death but I'm a developer and curious, so I thought this would be a great opportunity to learn a bit more of powershell :)

**Device Class Guid**

[image: Device manager property]

**Powershell script**

```
# Get the display adapter
$adapter = Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName "NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070" | Where-Object {$_.ClassGuid -eq "{4d36e968-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}"}

# Disable the display adapter
Disable-PnpDevice -InstanceId $adapter.InstanceId

# Wait for 5 seconds
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

# Enable the display adapter
Enable-PnpDevice -InstanceId $adapter.InstanceId
```

**Error returned**

```
Performing the operation "Disable" on target "Win32_PnPEntity: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070 (DeviceID =                      "PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_2488&SUBSYS_138A196E&R...)".                                                                          
Disable-PnpDevice : Generic failure
At C:\Users\me\Desktop\NVIDIA_Reboot.ps1:5 char:1
+ Disable-PnpDevice -InstanceId $adapter.InstanceId
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Win32_PnPEntity..._138A196E&R...):ROOT\cimv2\Win32_PnPEntity) [Disable-Pn
   pDevice], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80041001,Disable-PnpDevice
```

Comment: _"Disable-PnpDevice : Generic failure"_ - Windows' error messages being helpful as always. is there anything relevant in any of your System Event Logs? (Be sure to check the logs buried under "Application and Service Logs", you might need to enable WPR/ETW traces to get _useful_ detailed messages too - in fact, you should try that first, tbh.

Comment: Found it! The secret is on the CimException.- need to run the script as an Admin (doh)

Answer (score 1):

Solution: run the script as an Admin (doh)

"CimException" on the error descriptions gives the clue, and [this article on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19279099/ddg#19280005) explains the context